# Getting "Error converting data type VARCHAR to DATETIM"E while copying data from Azure blob to Azure DW through Polybase

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, polybase

I am new to the Azure environment and i am using data factory while trying to copy data present in the CSV file on Azure blob storage which has three columns (id,age,birth date) to a table in Azure data warehouse. The birth date is of the format "MM/dd/yyyy" and i am using polybase to copy the data from blob to my table in azure DW. The columns of the table are defined as(int,int,datetime).

I can copy my data if i use "Bulk Insert" option in data factory but it gives me an error when i choose the Polybase copy. Also changing the dateformat in the pipleine does not do any good either.
Polybase copies successfully if i change the date format in my file to "yyyy/MM/dd".

Is there a way i can copy data from my blob to my table without having to change the date format in the source file to "yyyy/MM/dd".

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have created an external file format which you reference in your external table?

The `CREATE EXTERNAL FILEFORMAT` has an option to define how a date is represented: `DATE_FORMAT`, and you set that to how your source data represents datetime.

So something like so:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL FILE FORMAT your-format  
WITH 
(  
  FORMAT_TYPE = DELIMITEDTEXT,  
  FORMAT_OPTIONS (  
      FIELD_TERMINATOR = '|',  
      DATE_FORMAT = 'MM/dd/yyyy' ) 
);
```

You can find more about this at: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-external-file-format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Thanks Niels. I am not using external tables in my work. I used the azure web portal to create a blob storage and then uploaded a CSV file in the container inside the blob. 
I created a table inside the data warehouse as my destination data where i wanted my data to be copied. 
For copying data, i created a pipleline using Data Factory (all from the azure web portal) . For copying the data through this pipleline, i choose the polybase copy option. But due to the date format mismatch between the data in CSV file (format MM/dd/yyyy) and the DW table to be datetime,its giving me above error.

Comment: Ah, OK - I do not know that much about Data Factory, but I would assume you can define the date format when you create a data pipeline in ADF?

Comment: Thanks Niels for your help. I was able to copy data from blob to data warehouse using the external tables with a format similar to as what you shared here. Also i was able to copy data using data factory from the azure portal by entering my date-format without qutoes. Removing the quotes did the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this error is resolved now. I was giving the date-format as 'MM/dd/yyyy' whereas the data factory expected it to be just MM/dd/yyyy without any quotes.

So as per my understanding i will summarize what i learned while copying data from Azure blob to Azure SQL Data Warehouse with a 'MM/dd/yyy' date format, in a few points here :

1) If you are using azure portal to copy data from blob to azure sql data warehouse using Data Factory copy option.

- Create a copy data pipe line using data factory.
- Specify your input data source and your destination data store.
- Under filed mappings,choose datetime in the column that contains the
  date, click on the little icon on its right to bring the custom date
  format field and enter your date format without quotes e.g.
  MM/dd/yyyy  as in my case.
- Run your pipleline and it should successfully complete.

2) You can use polybase directly by:

- Creating external data source that specifies the location of your
  input file e.g. csv file on blob storage in my case.
- An external file format that specifies the delimiter and custom date format e.g. MM/dd/yyyy in your
  input file.
- External table that defines all the columns present in your source
  file and uses the external data storage and file format which you
  defined above.
- You can then create your custom tables as select using the external
  table(CTAS).Something which Niels stated in his answer above.I used
  Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio for this process.